# Pivot table wording - SSMS 2012

Tags: sql, pivot, sql-server-2012, ssms, ssms-2012

I'm trying to pivot the PRODUCT column of a table.  Values that have two words have an underscore in between:

EX of some PRODUCT values:

```
PRODUCT
USSIC_Aviation
Avemco_Aviation
Property
Life
```

This is my pivot code:

```
select SIMULATION, [USSIC Aviation], [Avemco Aviation], [Property], [Life]
from CM.CorrelationData
pivot
(
min(Value)
for replace(PRODUCT,'_',' ') in ([USSIC Aviation], [Avemco Aviation], [Property], [Life])
) piv
where Product_Description='UW'
```

It doesn't like the `replace(PRODUCT,'_',' ')` but I don't know how else to get rid of the underscore.  Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot perform a replace in the `PIVOT` area of the query so you will need to perform it in a subquery:

```
select SIMULATION, [USSIC Aviation], [Avemco Aviation], [Property], [Life]
from
(
  select SIMULATION, replace(PRODUCT,'_',' ') Product, value
  from  CM.CorrelationData
  where Product_Description='UW' 
) d
pivot
(
  min(Value)
  for PRODUCT in ([USSIC Aviation], [Avemco Aviation], [Property], [Life])
) piv
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I forgot that!